# Store LatLong in cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

What I am trying to do is, store user LatLong in Cookie, but cookie not set after user allow for position, with no error or etc. What I have did wrong?

```js
var successCallback = function(position) {
  $.cookie('latlong', position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude, {
    expires: 360,
    path: '/'
  });
};

var errorCallback = function(error) {
  var errorMessage = 'Unknown error';
  switch (error.code) {
    case 1:
      errorMessage = 'Permission denied';
      break;
    case 2:
      errorMessage = 'Position unavailable';
      break;
    case 3:
      errorMessage = 'Timeout';
      break;
  }
};

var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 10000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/plugin/cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

Comment: Any errors in JS? How are you determining this isn't working? Have you checked the cookies collection directly in the browser? Is the success handler called?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Nope, no error. I checked browser cookie, there is no `latlong` cookie, yes directly (chrome). I am sure `getCurrentPosition` works fine because I insert an `console.log('ok');` in `successCallback` but cookie not set.

Comment: In which case this should in theory work. The only thing left to eliminate is to try removing `path: '/'`.

Comment: unfortunately still is the same @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: looks like the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` needs to be started by a user interaction... try to wrap it into a event handler... just to see if it is the case

Comment: your code working well.getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.

Comment: @flowerszhong I am using SSL already.